Proof of uniform convergence in $ [a,\infty)$ but not $[0, \infty)$
Let $f_n(x)=\frac{x}{(1+x)^n}$. I need to prove that $f(x)=\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f_n(x)$ is uniformly convergent in $[a,\infty), \forall a>0$ but not uniformly convergent in $[0,\infty)$. Is my proof correct?
Let $a \in R^{+}$ and let $x \in [a, \infty)$. $\left|\frac{1}{(1+x)}\right| < 1$, and therefore $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{1+x}\right)^n = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(1+x)^n}$ converges, and to the sum of $\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{1+x}}$. Which means $f(x) = \displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x}{(1+x)^n} = \frac{x}{1-\frac{1}{1+x}} = 1+x$.
The function series has pointwise convergence to a continuous function and all the functions are non-negative, and by Dini's
Theorem, there is a uniform convergence.
$f(0) = \frac{0}{1} = 0$. Therefore, in $[0,\infty), f(x)=0 $ for $x = 0$ and $1+x$ for $x \not=0$. Therefore, $f(x)$ is not continuous.
For all $S_n(x) = \displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{n}f_k(x)$ is continuous. If there was uniform convergence, then $f(x) = \lim_{n \to \infty} S_n(x)$ was continuous. Therefore there is no uniform convergence.

The idea is good. One small comment. The sum of the geometric series $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}r^k$ equals $\tfrac{r}{1-r}$. In this case the first term is not $1$. Also, you need to prove the uniform convergence in $[a,\infty).$

Dini's Theroem applies only to compact intervals. It does not apply to $[a, \infty)$.
